# Form after registration is not submitting Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

To complete registration, I want users to complete secondary form. However secondary form is not submitting. I think user is not getting authenticated in the registration and then the secondary form is not submitting. The login() seems to not work.

```
# the form in this view that's not submitting
def agreements(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AgreementsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            agree = form.save(commit=False)
            agree.save()
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Form is not valid. Try Again.")
    else:
        form = AgreementsForm()
    return render(request, 'agree.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the forms.py for the agreements:

```
class AgreementsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    non_ent=forms.BooleanField(label='kdmkl kdldsk')
    agreement1=forms.BooleanField(label='dmklsd. lkdfmld')

    class Meta:
        model = Agreements
        fields = ('non_ent', 'agreement1')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        agree = super(AgreementsForm, self).save(commit=False)
        agree.non_ent = self.cleaned_data['non_ent']
        agree.agreement1 = self.cleaned_data['agreement1']
        if commit:
            agree.save()
        return agree
```

Here is the initial registration view:

```
# register view which submits, but I think it's not authenticating the user
def registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save() 
            login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            return redirect('agreements_page')             
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Form is not valid. Try Again.")
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Agreements Model:

```
class Agreements(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    non_ent = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    agreement1 = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} ({self.date})'
```

Comment: what is your `Agreements` Model ?

Comment: and AFAIK is you want the user to authenticate using a username and a password then you use `authenticate()` not `login()`

Comment: @Moha - I had authenticate() and it still does not work and I'll add the agreements model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate user first to login :
def registration(request):

```
 if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save() 
            # authenticate user first
            user = authenticate(request,username=form.cleaned_data['username'],password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user:
               login(request, user)
               return redirect('agreements_page')
```

Then in your secondary form you can save `request.user` like this .
I hope you have a `OneToOne` relation with user in your `Agreement` model.

```
 form = AgreementsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            agree = form.save(commit=False)
            agree.user = request.user
            agree.save()
```

Comment: Thank you will try this.

Comment: Tried this, but still getting this error: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at>>": "Agreements.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: Is there an easy way to save my foreign key field to one-to-one. A migration is not working. I then tried to delete all my past migrations and it's still not changing the relationship.